# Account removal on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 64-bit, repository, accounts

Will removing an administrator account remove my ppas added in my repository?

Answer (score 0):

No, ppa and repositories are configured as a part of system configuration (apt) and not as a part of user accounts.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

You need access to root, ie an administrative login, to configure the system however.

Comment: So once ppas are added, they are permanent. Good. Just making sure as I have quite a few added. I also already have su configured. Never had to remove an account before, so I was making sure.

Comment: You can remove a ppa, but not by deleting an administrative user.